# Handling pictures, documents, etc. (Microsoft Azure)

Tags: sql, database, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am currently in the process of building a SQL database in Microsoft Azure for handling pictures, documents, etc. What is the most efficient/best way of storing data? Uploading the files directly to the DB, or by sourcing the files from something like Azure BLOB? I have read numerous posts about people uploading it directly to the DB, but I am concerned about its efficiency.

Thank you in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

You can store in something like Azure SQL DB for example but I would not recommend it, you should definitely store in Azure Storage (BLOB) and then for reference store in a DB. Azure has multiple relational and NoSQL data stores which are offered as platform services.

I would do two things, use a NoSQL platform data store like Cosmos DB using SQL Core API to store the metadata for the images, here you can use the filename as the partition ID to do a point read (this is very fast read and it would be a very cheap option with blazing fast performance) and secondly I would use Azure CDN to make sure images are accessed via CDN so that they are faster.

Azure CDN has three options; Akamai, Verizon and Microsoft. You can test which CDN is faster from where you are from here: https://cloudharmony.com/speedtest-for-azure

Using the above URL you can also use to test which Azure region is closer to you so to use that region, or test for your end-users and choose the region closer tot them.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. It definitely seems like a good solution. Are there any security issues/challenges referencing data in the DB? Can a reference retrieved once be used to access media without consent at a later stage? (Similar to a public URL)

Comment: i would recommend not putting the full URL in your DB as a column, in-fact use relative URLs and use your 'web app\custom app' settings to store the URL in app settings or web.config file. The reason for this as you stated is of course security but also you might change your storage account later or even move to different azure region.

Answer (score 0):

I would say storing in Azure BLOBs is a better idea. Imagine you have 100 GB files stored in DB.

- It will slow down your query if your table is not designed properly.
- Backup & Restore DB will be very slow.
- Azure DB is more expensive than Azure BLOB for the same size.

If your total file size is small enough, it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: Thank you for your insights and for confirming my thoughts.